# Can we query (and use) field value from package without becoming dependant on that package?

Tags: apex, soql, package

I have a case where I would like to use a field from a 3rd party package in my package, if that package is not installed in the target org I can use a default value.

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30070/check-managed-app-is-installed-or-not) tells me how I can check if the package is installed, but is it possible to query data from a custom field provided by that package if it exists?

I have tried something like:

```
if(Type.forName('ns__KnownObjectInPackage__c') != null) {
 // SOQL query to return the field value from ns__KnownObjectInPackage__c
}else{
 // Use a default value
}
```

but it will not compile in my dev org complaining that the package is not installed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more direct answer than Phil's is to say that using dynamic SOQL avoids locking in a dependency so is the way to go. I would just wrap the query in a try/catch (not near an org to check what the most appropriate type to catch would be) and use the default value when the exception is thrown because the 3rd party object/field is missing.

We have packaged code of this nature working well. Always double check before uploading a new package version that you haven't accidentally introduced a hard (compile time) dependency on the 3rd party package.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly possible to do it, but what you can do is implement a workaround in your Dev org.

What you can do is create the Object/Field (or use an existing one) in your code and then reference that in your DE org only by checking the Org ID in your code - then in other target orgs, use the real field/object, for example:

```
String fieldToQuery = 'YourSpoofField__c';
String objectToQuery = 'YourSpoofObject__c';
if(UserInfo.getOrganizationId() != 'YOUR DE ORG ID')
{
    fieldToQuery = 'ns__TheRealDealField__c';
    objectToQuery = 'ns__TheRealDealObject__c';
}

// use dynamic SOQL query
List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT ' + fieldToQuery + ' FROM ' + objectToQuery);
```

Ideally, you'd install the package in your org as this is really just a hack/workaround.

Comment: Hi Phil, Your reply is good and gets me half way there. I think you slightly misunderstood in that it's in the target org that the package may or may not exist, thus the requirement for no dependency. I have edited my question as once I have the record with the value I need in an sObject, I would like to be able to access it! Can I get the value of the field using the same string manipulation technique? If so how?